# Read user input until a specific character is encountered

Tags: c

Can someone please provide me some examples? Thank you :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tcount = 0, ccount = 0, dcount = 0;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter your characters (! to end): \n");

    /* What program code to write to get the result? */

    printf("digits: %d\n", dcount);
    printf("letters: %d\n", ccount);
    return 0;
}
```

is it using for loop?

```
    for (tcount=0;tcount<10;tcount++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch == '!')
            break;
    }
```

Test Result:

hello 5432 user#

digits: 4  letters: 9

Comment: Hint: `getchar()`

Comment: Does your assignment restrict it to a maximum of 10 characters input? If so, a for loop is appropriate. If not, then a while loop would be a more suitable choice.

Comment: unless you can put the input into raw mode the user is going to have to press enter before the results will display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` for reading single characters.

Or if you have to, you have to skip leading whitespaces

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
       ^                 Note the space
```

---

Here is a simple example which could be helpful to you, using functions `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` from `ctype.h` library.

```
int c, numberCounter = 0, letterCounter = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '!')
{
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        letterCounter++;
    }
    else if (isdigit(c))
    {
        numberCounter++;
    }
}
```

If you can't use additional libraries like `ctype.h`, take a look at the [ASCII](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table, for example

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')  // '0' == 48, '9' == 57
{
    // c is digit
}
```

Comment: Is there another way without using additional library?

Comment: @Bexie the C library is there to be used! You could test for a digit with `if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')` because C *requires* thoses digits to be encoded consecutively. But although the ASCII character set is in common use, C does not require the same of the alphabet. So the use of `isalpha()` is not only portable but less clumsy than `if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')`. The [EBCDIC set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
do
{
    char c = getchar();
    if(c!='!')
    {
         ... do something .... 
    }

}
while(c != '!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use a loop for, or a while:

```
 for (tcount=0;tcount<10;tcount++)
{
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch == '!')
        break;
}
```

or the while code:

```
while(ch != '!'){
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("There are nothing to see here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX `getdelim` function does exactly what you're asking for (most code floating around uses `getline`, but it is exactly the same other than the extra argument). Beware the possibility that the delimiter does *not* occur within the buffer size.

Also, for interactive input, you might want to put the TTY in raw mode, or the user will have to press enter anyway.